# Debugger (C) steps into stdio.h library, how do i prevent that?

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

I have a "problem" about my debugger.

When I debug, I usually use the command `step into`, to go forward, and everything was going smooth. Then some day, when I `stepped into` a function like `printf()`, or `fscanf()`, the debugger started taking me into the actual library, `<stdio.h>`...

I know I can avoid this just using the command `step over`, but I'm really used to debug my code easily and fast, just by pressing constantly the same button, and I don't want to switch every 3 seconds from `step into` to `step over`, because I want to focus on my code flow...

Can anyone help me please?

If you need other info, of course I'm going to give them to you.

Comment: There's usually a "step out" command, that steps out of the current function.

Comment: You have tagged both `visual-studio-code` and `gdb`. Clarify which debugger you are using.

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged *Visual Studio Code,* I am answering for the debugger in that IDE. To execute and then leave a function you have entered while debugging, you can press `SHIFT F11`. (This would in effect be "the opposite" of entering a function, which is `F11`.) From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debug---step-out) a description of **Step Out** can be found:

> "Click Step Out on the Debug menu to resume running on the target.
> This command executes the rest of the current function and breaks when
> the function return is completed."

Answer (score 1):

You can use `~/.gdbinit` configuration file, see man [gdbinit](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/gdbinit.5.html)

```
skip file /usr/include/stdio.h
```

You can check it in `gdb` using `info skip`:

```
(gdb) info skip
Num   Enb Glob File                 RE Function
1     y      n /usr/include/stdio.h  n <none>
(gdb)
```

---

You can `skip` a whole file `skip file /what/ever.c` or a function : `skip printf`